# convert date to UTC ISO midnight

Tags: javascript, date

trying to create new date and set it to UTC ISO midnight and get output as following "2017-07-12T00:00:00" but no luck so far.

```
var dateNow = new Date();
var dateToUTC = dateNow.setUTCHours(0,0,0,0);
/*this gives me an error msg*/
var dateToISO = dateToUTC.toISOString();
```

Comment: Note that you should also have a trailing a `Z` in your output, unless you actually mean the local date.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`Date.setUTCHours` doesn't return a date, it returns a number ([see the docs, here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setUTCHours)) and mutates the date.

You want this:

```
var dateNow = new Date();
dateNow.setUTCHours(0,0,0,0);
var dateToISO = dateNow.toISOString();
```